# Potential file handling logic error

Tags: pascal

```pascal
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var

count:integer;

filename:string;

begin

  count:=1;

  repeat

    filename:= 'questions/question '+ IntToStr(count)+'.txt';

    if not fileexists(fileName) then

    begin

      Assignfile (FileQ, filename);

      ReWrite(FileQ);

      CloseFile(FileQ);

    end;

    Assignfile (FileQ, filename);

    Append(FileQ);

    WriteLn (FileQ, Question_Enter);

    WriteLn (FileQ, OptionA);

    WriteLn (FileQ, OptionB);

    WriteLn (FileQ, OptionC);

    WriteLn (FileQ, OptionD);

    CloseFile(FileQ);

    count := count + 1;

  until count > 5;

end;
```

So the idea with this algorithm is that the user can add their own multiple choice questions and answers by entering the question and choices in separate edit boxes and then pressing one button to send the block of text to a text file. This algorithm currently makes 5 completely identical text files (other than the name which is 'question1, question2.. to question5').  I want it to just produce one text file with the information in, but to increment the name of the text file so that the next time they add a question, the text file is known as 'question2' and has completely different contents and so on.  I apologise if this is a really dumb question or if it is too vague, I'm also not sure about how I formatted the block of code either.

Answer (score 0):

Write a marker so that you recognize a question when reading the results back, e.g. prefix each question with ! or @.

Then reading is

```
n:=0;              // nr of questions
while not eof do
  begin
    readln(f,s);
    if (length(s)>0) and (s[1]='!') then
      begin        
        inc(n);
        delete(s,1);
        storenewquestion(n,s);
      end
    else
     begin
       storenewanswer(n,s);
     end;
   end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however I'm having problems implementing this into my code.  What are f and s ? And what should I declare them as?  And what about storenewquestion and storenewanswer?  Thanks again

Comment: S is a variabele of type string, f is equal to FileQ in your application. Storenew* are procedures that do something with the read results, like store them in an array. To that extend they get the number of the record (n) in the first parameter. The record numbers are starting with 1.